# On click, remove hyperlink in contenteditable div

Tags: html, jquery

I want a version of `removeAttr()` that removes the `<a>` and `</a>` tags as well as the `href` attribute of a link when the link is clicked.

`$(this).contents().unwrap()` and `replaceWith()` are not the desired solution because when they are applied in a `contendteditable` div, they move the cursor to the beginning of the `unwrapped` word instead of maintaining the cursor at its original position.

Consider the following:

```js
$('a').click(function(e){//Place cursor middle of "Google" e.g "Go|ogle"
    $(this).contents().unwrap(); //moves cursor to start of "Google" e.g "|Google"
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = "editor" contenteditable = "true">
    <a href = "go.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

On the other hand, when `removeAttr()` is applied to `<a href = "https://go.com">Google</a>`, `href = "https://go.com"` is removed but the cursor remains at its original position as desired.

Therefore, I want a version of `removeAttr()` that removes the `<a>`and `</a>` tags as well as the `href` attribute of a link when the link is clicked.

Comment: Any changes to the html *structure* of a contenteditable (or text of an input) will move the caret (cursor poition) - you need to store it (the caret) before the change then put it back in an appropriate/relevant location.

Comment: `removeAttr()` does not move the caret. @freedomn-m kindly assist me with the idea you suggest. Could you provide code example how it could store the caret and then put it back after making the changes?

Comment: `removeAttr` doesn't change the *structure* of the html

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+store+caret+editable